# I m not receiving real time stream because receivePacket is the most 1024 bytes

Tags: android, sockets, video-streaming, byte

i want to do real time stream from my pc to android device with WIFI. Server code is written by Java. My codes is running true. when I clicked the button in android, in server, sendPacket is actived and it sends packet. I send 65000 bytes(sendPacket) from server, but client receive is 1024 bytes(receivePacket). that' s problem. If sendPacket is smaller, view is very bad.Thank you for your helps...

main.java(server)

```
public class main {

private static JFrame jframeImage;
private static FacePanel panelImage;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private static ThreadSender threadSender;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.PORT_ADDRESS);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    threadSender = new ThreadSender(socket);
    threadSender.start();
    initFrame();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    VideoCapture camFeed = new VideoCapture(0);
    Mat matCamFeed = new Mat();
    Mat matSender = new Mat();
    byte[] clientInformation = new byte[10];
    DatagramPacket packetClientInf = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Client Bekleniyor....");
        packetClientInf = new DatagramPacket(clientInformation,
                clientInformation.length);
        socket.receive(packetClientInf);
        System.out.println("Client baglandi.");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Constants.IP_ADDRESS = packetClientInf.getAddress();
    Constants.CLIENT_PORT = packetClientInf.getPort();
    System.out.println("client ip:"+packetClientInf.getAddress());
    System.out.println("client port: "+packetClientInf.getPort());
    String s = new String(packetClientInf.getData());
    System.out.println("gelen data: "+s);

    while (true) {
        camFeed.read(matCamFeed);
        Imgproc.resize(matCamFeed, matSender, new Size(150, 150));
        BufferedImage bufImage = null;
        try {
            bufImage = matToBufferedImage(matSender);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        threadSender.setBufImageForSend(bufImage);
        threadSender.run();
        panelImage.setImage(bufImage);
        panelImage.repaint();
    }

}

public static void initFrame() {
    jframeImage = new JFrame("Image from client");
    jframeImage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframeImage.setSize(400, 400);
    jframeImage.setVisible(true);

    JButton btnGonder = new JButton("gonder");
    btnGonder.setVisible(true);

    panelImage = new FacePanel();


    jframeImage.setContentPane(panelImage);

}

public static BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat mat) throws IOException {
    MatOfByte bytemat = new MatOfByte();

    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", mat, bytemat);

    byte[] bytes = bytemat.toArray();

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
    return img;
}
```

}

ThreadSender.java

```
public class ThreadSender extends Thread {

private BufferedImage bufImageForSend;
private DatagramSocket socket;

public ThreadSender(DatagramSocket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    bufImageForSend = null;
}

public void setBufImageForSend(BufferedImage bufImageForSend) {
    this.bufImageForSend = bufImageForSend;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.run();

    if (bufImageForSend != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufImageForSend, "jpeg", bos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        byte[] byteImage = bos.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("Total image byte length: " + byteImage.length);

        if (byteImage.length <= 65500) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(byteImage,
                    byteImage.length, Constants.IP_ADDRESS, Constants.CLIENT_PORT);
            try {
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

Client.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText messageEdit;
Button sendButton;
TextView informationText;
ImageView image;
CheckBox devam;
int PORT=999;
InetAddress IPAddress;
String serverHostname = new String("172.28.8.44");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    messageEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    devam = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            try {
                IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverHostname);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
                            DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
                            try {
                                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                            } catch (SocketException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            String sentence = messageEdit.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                                    sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress,
                                    PORT);
                            try {
                                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(
                                    receiveData, receiveData.length);

                            try {
                                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                                        byte[] b = receivePacket.getData();

                                    ByteArrayInputStream ba=new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
                                    BufferedInputStream bi=new BufferedInputStream(ba);
                                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                        .decodeStream(bi);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                        image.invalidate();
                                    }
                                });

                                clientSocket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }).start();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });
        }
```

}

Comment: Ummm... 'byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];'  Remainder of datagram is discarded.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh :). really thank you, we have studied on this for one week. We will thank you in final project... :)))